Chrome processes are using more than 100% of the CPU, causing the PC to freeze
Google Chrome is behaving very erratically and their processes uses more than 100% and the computer is lagging in general.
If I reboot the computer the problem disappears for a while until I load chrome again and I start working.
I do not have to many programs opened, just OS and chrome with many tabs.
Any idea what the problem is?
Specs:

Intel i7 8 cores
16 GiB RAM
GeForce GTX 860M

Chrome:

Consinue running backgroud apps when is closed
Uses graphics acceleration when available



To vague question. Do you notice this behavior when opening a specific tab? (For example: For me, it happened when I opened Spotify). Do you have a graphics card? Is Chrome running with hardware acceleration? Try to press Shift + ESC to open Chrome task manager.

Not using more programs but chrome and system processes. Chrome is using graphics acceleration when available and I have a old graphics card. Chrome task manager did not show anything it takes my eye

tried testing wayland and after, Xorg ?

no, how would that be?

At login screen you can chosse between Wayland and Xorg for Graphical User Interface
